What かまって means in かまって新卒ちゃんが毎回誘ってくる
There is a manga with title かまって新卒ちゃんが毎回誘ってくる. I am wondering about what かまって means here. I suspect かまって新卒ちゃん is a combination of 構ってちゃん and 新卒? Maybe not because if that's case, then it will be written as 新卒かまってちゃん.

Yes, かまって新卒ちゃん is a combination of 構ってちゃん and 新卒. It could have been 新卒(の)かまってちゃん, too. The order doesn't make much difference, but maybe かまって新卒ちゃん may look a bit more "unique".
